# Babel output file not exist

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs

I try to compile es5 js file using `Babel`, but get file doesn`t exist error.

command:

```
npm run babel ./application/modules/js/seatMap/services/BabelTest.js --output-file ./application/modules/reservation_module/js/seatMap/services/babelOutput.js
```

error after command execution:

```
./application/modules/reservation_module/js/seatMap/services/babel.js doesn't exist
```

I use `--output-file` param for specifying output file, but node tell me that the file not exist